# Adding a hrule between hboxes decreases their vertical distance

Tags: spacing, pdftex, tex-core, boxes, rules

Using pdftex.

Given two sample programs

test0.tex

```
\vbox{
\hbox{X}
\hbox{Y}
}

\bye
```

test1.tex

```
\vbox{
\hbox{X}
\hrule
\hbox{Y}
}

\bye
```

gives the following outputs.

test0.png

[image: test0.png]

test1.png

[image: test1.png]

So, adding a `\hrule` between the two `\hbox`es actually decreases their vertical distance.

Why is this and what parameters influence the vertical distance between two sibling hboxes?

Comment: if you want to retain the vertical spacing, it's usually sufficient to add a `\strut` to the end of the first and the beginning of the second line.  there are other places that a `\strut` can be beneficial, for example a line with no descenders at the end of a multi-line table cell.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the TeXbook, page 79 (last single dangerous bend)

> Exception: No interline glue is inserted before or after a rule
>   box. You can also inhibit interline glue by saying `\nointerlineskip`
>   between boxes.

In the case without the rule, the interline glue is added as usual: compute the sum *s* of the depth of the upper line and the height of the lower line; if the difference *b* – *s* (where *b* is the natural length of `\baselineskip`) is greater than `\lineskiplimit`, insert glue of length *b* – *s* (with the `plus` and `minus` components of `\baselineskip`); otherwise, insert `\lineskip` glue.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for! (Or, not so great: the rule sounds complicated. I'll have to read up on glue again).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is not a property that is unique to \hbox. The happens due the default spacing defined above and below the `\hrule` construct. You can change the spacing manually by using the `\kern` command.

```
\vbox{
\hbox{X}
\hrule
\kern2pt %change the pts according to your needs
\hbox{Y}
}
```

Alternatively, you could also define a macro for this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this:

```
\newdimen\savedprevdepth

\vbox{
\hbox{X}
\savedprevdepth=\prevdepth \hrule \prevdepth=\savedprevdepth
\hbox{Y}
}

\bye
```

Explanation: `\prevdepth` primitive register is set to the depth of the last box in the vertical list. It is set to magic value `-1000pt` when the vertical list is empty or when the `\hrule` is inserted to the vertical list. The `\baselineskip`/`\lineskiplimit`/`\lineskip` processing for the next box is active only if `\prevdepth` isn't equal to `-1000pt`.

Comment: "Maybe" and the shortness of the answer qualify this rather as a comment. Did you check it or can provide an output?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK, I added more information. I hoped that this info is simply available for interested persons.